# Titles with thumbnails in media library

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, images

I have about 3000 products and need to assign images to them. The images all have titles including the product name, but this does not display along with the thumbnail when I look at the media library, which makes the image assignment very difficult for someone who does nt recognise the product thumbnail. How do I get the titles to be displayed with the thumbnail?

Answer (score 0):

You need to view the Media Library in "List View" instead of "Grid view". Look just below the text "Media Library" at the top of the screen for a list icon / grid icon (grid will be selected) and switch to List.

Here's an article that shows a screenshot: https://easywpguide.com/wordpress-manual/media-library/